# Convert div/ui grid to svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, ui-grid

I need to be able to convert UI grid or a div that contains it into svg. So far I have used library called html2canvas, pass it a div id and export it into a canvas. Now I'm stuck as there is no way I can find that would allow me to take that generated canvas and export to svg. Is there any way I can achieve that ? Or maybe my approach is wrong ?

```
public hello =()=>{

    //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
    let element = document.getElementById('container');
    html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {

    });
};
```

Comment: SVG is a *vector* format. Converting random HTML elements to a vector format isn't going to be an easy task, if it's possible at all. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Share the working fiddle please.

Comment: Have you looked up fabric.js ?

Comment: Www.cloudformattet.com is a JS library with external formatter that supports creating svg from a div